# Erlang queue inconsistent behaviour

Tags: erlang, queue

There are differences  in internal representation of the queues depending on:

- either it was created using **queue:from_list()** function
- or using **queue:new()** function and them populating with elements.

Simple Code:

```
L = [1,2,3], 
Q = queue:from_list(L),  % convert it to Queue.
L2 = queue:to_list(Q),   % convert back to list.
QL2 = queue:from_list(L2), % And create queue representation
true =  Q =:= QL2.
```

So far everything is OK,

- Q looks like:  **{[3],[1,2]}**
- QL2 looks like **{[3],[1,2]}**

Now create queue by elements:

```
Q0 = queue:new(),
Q1 = queue:in(1,Q0),
Q2 = queue:in(2,Q1),
Q3 = queue:in(3,Q2),
Q =:= Q3.
```

**false**

- Q:  **{[3],[1,2]}**
- Q3: **{[3,2],[1]}**

Internal representation of Q and Q3 is different.

if we do things like:

```
Q3x = queue:from_list(queue:to_list(Q3))
```

We get the same representation: **{[3],[1,2]}**

And now:

```
Q =:= Q3x.
```

**true** 
  as expected.

This mean we can not compare 2 queues for equality just using code like:

```
Q == Q3.
```

Is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve? If the check for equality isn't too frequent or in a hot code path, have you considered converting each queue to a list via `queue:to_list/1`, sorting each list, and comparing those instead?

Answer (score 3):

The question is: if you out or out_r elements from both queues, do they give the same results? As the answer is yes, there is no inconsistent behavior.

The internal representation is an "opaque" tuple which content depend on the history of the queue, how it was filled end emptied. This structure is there to optimized the operations with queue, and it is not reliable to write your code based on the actual representation since it is possible (even if not likely) that this representation change. One consequence is that yo cannot compare queues with pattern matching or ==, and there is no interface to do it, I guess that it is because this use case is rather seldom.
If you really need it, I guess that the more efficient solution is to compare the the results of queue:to_list/1: `queue:to_list(Q) == queue:to_list(Q3).`

Comment: You are right, the internal representation is an "opaque",but if we do the same things with the dictionary: `L = [{1,a},{2,b},{3,c}], DL= dict:from_list(L), D0 = dict:new(), D1 = dict:store(1,a,D0),D2 = dict:store(2,b,D1), D3 = dict:store(3,c,D2),  true = DL =:= D3.` Then everything is OK. So I would expect the same behavior from the queue. Similar check for array works too. Looks like  the only exception  is queue

Comment: The dictionary approach will fail once you hit items that hash to the same value, where the dict starts maintaining a list of values that share the same hash -- at that point, insertion order becomes significant in the structure of the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

According to algorithm complexity estimation technique called "Amortized analysis" some operations may "pay" for other operations. In this particular case with queue there is two lists representing queue: front list (which is used for constant add time) and rear list (which is used for constant access time).
Elements from front list sometimes may migrate into rear list and it is up to implementation when it will happen.

I found a paper "Amortized Analysis Explained by Rebecca Fiebrink Princeton University" very helpful in this subject. One of it's example is exactly your question.